# python explicitly not passing optional parameter

Tags: python, optional-parameters

imagine the following scenario:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg1=3, arg2=5):
        pass

def createA(arg1=None, arg2=None):
    if arg1 is None:
        if arg2 is None:
            a = A()
        else:
            a = A(arg2=arg2)
    else:
        if arg2 is None:
            a = A(arg1=arg1)
        else:
            a = A(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
    return a
```

Whats the best way to implement this behavior, with the followings in mind:

- I can't/don't want to change class `A`
- I don't want to explicitly add the default values of `A`'s constructor's parameters to the `createA` function?

For example is there any value that indicates a not passed optional argument?
Something like:

```
if arg1 is None:
    newArg1 = NotPassed
else:
    newArg1 = arg1

if arg2 is None:
    newArg2 = NotPassed
else:
    newArg2 = arg2
A(arg1=newArg1, arg2=newArg2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def create_A(arg1=None, arg2=None):
    kwargs = {}
    if arg1 is not None: kwargs['arg1'] = arg1
    if arg1 is not None: kwargs['arg2'] = arg2
    return A(**kwargs)
```

or maybe even

```
def create_A(**kwargs):
    return A(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Very nice, I'm just wondering why Python as a modern language does not provide a special value for this behaviour.  Something like `A(arg1=1, arg2=Empty)` maybe...